# Какие библиотеки можно использовать для воспроизведения звука в linux (Raspbian) для приложений на C#?

Tags: c#, аудио, raspbian, avalonia

Приложение на C# Avalonia для Raspberry Pi на ОС Raspbian 10 и Raspbian 11. Нужно воспроизвести звуковой файл (mp3, wav или любой другой звуковой формат, который можно записать на микрофон или записать и в пару действий преобразовать). Какую библиотеку не смотрю, у всех зависимости с Windows. Например, последней пробовал, NAudio. Выводятся ошибки `Unable to load shared library 'Msacm32.dll' or one of its dependencies.` для mp3 и `Unable to load shared library 'winmm.dll' or one of its dependencies.` для wav. Погуглив, я так понял, что это чисто библиотеки для Windows. Код такой:

```
var reader = new Mp3FileReader(path);
var waveOut = new WaveOutEvent(); 
waveOut.Init(reader);
waveOut.Play();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714162/cross-platform-audio-library-for-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использую вариант ManagedBass из комментария. Скачал BASS Version: 2.4.17. В проекте использую avalonia 0.10.21, net 7.0. Вот код:

```
Bass.Init(); // Initialize with default options.
int handle = Bass.CreateStream("Sound.mp3");
Bass.ChannelPlay(handle); // Begin Playback.
// Если не делать задержку, то звук сразу выключается следующей функцией
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Bass.ChannelStop(handle); // Stop Playback.
// Эту строку я закомментировал, потому что этот метод переименовали, убрали или я его не нашёл.        
//Bass.ChannelFree(handle); // Free the Stream.
Bass.Free(); // Free the device.
```

Для работы необходимо добавить звуки, скачать с официального сайта библиотеки и добавить всё в сборку. Для Windows достаточно bass.dll из bass24. Для Raspberry необходима libbass.so из bass24-linux\libs\armhf.